encountering an unknown error with lambda function when I open the service
when I opened lambda function service, encountering an unknown error. I used free tier account. how to solve this problem?


Just check or ask the owner/admin to see if the current iam user has the necessary permissions to access lambda, you can also check browser devtools->network to check for http error codes.

The error message "UnknownError" on the AWS Lambda Functions page can occur for a few reasons:
IAM permissions: The IAM user you are logged in with might not have the necessary permissions to list Lambda functions. Check the IAM policy attached to the user and make sure it includes the lambda:ListFunctions permission. [AWS IAM permissions for Lambda ON
docs.aws.amazon.com]
Service issue: In rare cases, the error could be due to an issue with the AWS Lambda service itself. You can check the AWS Service Health Dashboard (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/aws-health-dashboard-status.html) to see if there are any reported issues with Lambda.
Browser caching: Try clearing your browser cache and reloading the page.
If you have checked the IAM permissions and there are no service issues, you can try clearing your browser cache or using a different browser to see if that resolves the issue.
I found this Re:Post that explains the same
https://repost.aws/questions/QUPpcS3wYaR12wHug50trqQQ/unknown-error-in-lambda

I was also facing same issue even though I'm logged in as root user. generally root user has all access to AWS services but was showing Unknown error.
In my case, after checking AWS Health Dashboard I came to know AWS suspended my some services like lambda for being my account compromised. Reason was my teammates were using same root credentials, access key for task from different machine.
For resolution: Please check with AWS team if anything stopped from there side. You can create a ticket case here for same. They will help you
https://support.console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/
